# 'Windows media player' コントロールをフォームに置くとエラーが出る

Tags: c#, visual-studio

フォームアプリにおいて、フォームデザイナーに 'Windows media player' コントロールを配置して、保存すると下記のようなエラーが出ます。

```
CS1752  相互運用型 'AxWindowsMediaPlayer' を埋め込むことができません。該当するインターフェイスを使用してください。
CS1752  相互運用型 'AxWindowsMediaPlayer' を埋め込むことができません。該当するインターフェイスを使用してください。
```

Comment: 他の人が状況を理解して問題を再現・調査出来るくらいの詳細な情報やソースコードを記述してください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765) ちなみにこんな記事 [Microsoft Visual Studio で Windows メディア プレーヤー コントロールを使用する](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/wmp/using-the-windows-media-player-control-with-microsoft-visual-studio) があるようですが、前後のページも含めて参考になるのではありませんか？

Answer (score 0):

この辺のMicrosoftの記事やその前後のページを参考に作業してみましょう。
[Microsoft Visual Studio で Windows メディア プレーヤー コントロールを使用する](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/wmp/using-the-windows-media-player-control-with-microsoft-visual-studio)

上記記事を元に作業を行った場合、デフォルトではVisualStudioのソリューションエクスプローラーのウインドウ上の「参照」の中の「AxWMPLib」のプロパティの「相互運用型の埋め込み」は「False」のはずですが、それを「True」に変更するとビルドにて質問のエラーが発生します。

「AxWMPLib」のプロパティの「相互運用型の埋め込み」は元の「False」に戻しておいてください。(「WMPLib」の方も変えていたら戻しておいてください)

質問の「保存すると」という操作では発生しないはずなので、何か違うこと(VisualStudioか.NETの版数が違うとか？)があるのかもしれませんが。(あるいは保存操作でビルド(やコードをチェックする処理)が行われる設定とか？)

問題が解決しないようなら、コメントに書いたように詳しい情報を追記してください。

[image: ソリューションエクスプローラー]

[image: プロパティ]
上記の赤丸部分は元は **False** ですが、**True** に変えてビルドすると以下のエラーとなります。

[image: エラーウインドウ]

ちなみに他の対処方法としてこんな記事があります。
[.NET FrameworkでWindows Media Player Controlを利用するもう一つの方法](https://qiita.com/fujieda/items/d8642eae891d096d4028)